# How often does the supermassive black hole in the Milky Way become a quasar?

Tags: supermassive-black-hole, quasars

My current interest is black holes and quasars. I was wondering how often they erupt--specifically ours? Would it be blindingly bright on Earth? Finally, would there be any effects that would alter our life on Earth that we know of?

Comment: At least it was somehow active 2.5 to 4.0 million years ago according to [this talk by Andrew Fox](http://aas.org/media-press/archived-aas-press-conference-webcasts) at the AAS2015, click "The Milky Way & Local Group", watch 15 minutes into it. And that event created the huge Fermi Bubbles. It indicates to me that it happens often and is harmless to us.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Was the Milky Way ever a quasar?](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1651/was-the-milky-way-ever-a-quasar)

Comment: @LocalFluff Very cool! What I gathered from that, combined with other information I've picked up, is that there is usually always something being forced out from a black hole pending on how much it is accumulating. That being said, it seems like since it's not a very active black hole that is does not have a quasar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, the black hole in the milky way was never a quasar, and as it currently stands will never become one.

Info about how earth and life on earth could be affected if this ever happened, can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-pm1WzeTkAg).

Comment: That was a very good video. It cleared up a lot of misconceptions I had as well. Thanks!